# Solving the system $O_i=\frac1m\log(e^{v_im}+I_i^p\ell)$, with $i=1,2,3$, for $m$, $p$, $\ell$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, exponentiation

I am writing a program to calculate three values from three equations. The three equations are based on one equation with variables substituted in each time.

The base equation:

$$O = \frac{\log(e^{vm} + I^p \ell)}{m}$$

We already know three sets of values for $O$, $I$, and $v$. Importantly, $v_1 = 0$ and $O_2 = 0$, allowing us to simplify further. The final equations are:
$$\begin{align}
O_1 &= \frac{\log(1 + I_1^p\ell)}{m} \\[6pt]
0   &= \frac{\log(e^{v_2m} + I_2^p \ell)}{m} \\[6pt]
O_3 &= \frac{\log(e^{v_3m} + I_3^p \ell)}{m}
\end{align}$$

How do I algebraically calculate the values of $m$, $p$, and $\ell$?

Comment: It looks like the two relations you introduce by the "Additionally" part make two more equations. So you have 5 equations in only 3 unknowns, which even for simple linear equations may not have a solution.

Comment: I understood that the "Additionally" part can be taken alone to give the three equations I need to solve. I'll modify the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Oh I think I see. So you're really starting with the three equations after "giving us" which do have unknowns $m,p,l$--but they also contain references to $v_2$ and to $O_1,O_3.$ Are these treated as constants which can appear in a proposed solution?

Comment: That's right, yes - all of $O_1$, $O_2$, $O_3$, $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$, $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ are constants that can appear in the solution. I gave $O_2$ and $v_1$ as they're always zero, and I expect that helps people solve it a bit. I've been trying to solve this myself and knowing they were zero gave me some progress.

Comment: I doubt that these equations have an algebraic solution. Even searching for a numerical solution smells like a hard problem.

Comment: Could I prove that some way?